# Firebug catching all exceptions

Tags: firebug

After updating firebug, it has been behaving very weird.  Firebug, for some reason, breaks everywhere there are exceptions.  I'm working in SharePoint, and I get so many breaks, its like torture.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Thanks!

Comment: Open `Console` tab, below the tabs on top there's a second row, which starts from the "Pause" button. If it's blinking, it means "Break on all errors" is active. Click it to disable.

Comment: OMG!  Thanks a lot for the help!  I always show it blinking, but never thought that was the culprit.  I always looked through the Script tab.  Thanks a ton for the help.  Can you post this as an answer so I can give you the credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `Console` tab, below the tabs on top there's a second row, which starts from the "Pause" button. If it's blinking, it means "Break on all errors" is active. Click it to disable.